# How can my Kotlin API classes be constructed from json? (using Moshi)

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I am refactoring and adding to the API communication of an app. I'd like to get to this usage for my "json data objects". Instantiate with either the properties directly or from a json string.

```
userFromParams = User("user@example.com", "otherproperty")
userFromString = User.fromJson(someJsonString)!!
// userIWantFromString = User(someJsonString)
```

Getting userFromParams to serialize to JSON was not a problem. Just adding a toJson() function takes care of that.

```
data class User(email: String, other_property: String) {
    fun toJson(): String {
        return Moshi.Builder().build()
                .adapter(User::class.java)
                .toJson(this)
    }

    companion object {
        fun fromJson(json: String): User? {
            val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
            return moshi.adapter(User::class.java).fromJson(json)
        }
    }
}
```

It is "fromJson" that I would like to get rid of ...because... I want to and I can't figure out how. The above class works (give or take wether to allow an optional object to be returned or not and so on) but it just bugs me that I get stuck trying to get to this nice clean overloaded initialization.

It does not strictly have to be a data class either, but it does seem appropriate here.

Comment: Cache your Moshi instance and your User JsonAdapter for reuse. Adapters are meant to be non-trivial to create and fast to reuse.

Comment: Sure. This was just a quick and dirty nonsense example class. But thanks for clarifying that is it not good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do that in any performant way. Any constructor invocation will instantiate a new object, but since Moshi handles object creation internally, you'll have two instances...

If you really REALLY want it though, you can try something like:

```
class User {
    val email: String
    val other_property: String

    constructor(email: String, other_property: String) {
        this.email = email
        this.other_property = other_property
    }

    constructor(json: String) {
        val delegate = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(User::class.java).fromJson(json)
        this.email = delegate.email
        this.other_property = delegate.other_property
    }

    fun toJson(): String {
        return Moshi.Builder()
                .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
                .build()
                .adapter(User::class.java)
                .toJson(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. That satisfies my curiosity... even thought I will probably take your advice and not generate excessive instances.